# Click on Custom keyboard in iOS using perfecto Mobile Webdriver

Tags: ios, selenium, webdriver

I want to click on the custom keyboard in the iOS using perfecto mobile webdriver. I have tried `sendKeys()` function but it didn,t worked out. Can you please help me to solve the issue. I am stuck because of this issue. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the value by finding the field object you want to set, and then set its value using the `sendKeys()` method?

Something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath of object, e.g. login)).sendKeys("whatever value you want");
```

You can replace the search to be by `ID` or `any other method`.